# Смена ip на Android программно

Tags: android, android-studio, ip

Прошу объяснить мне какие есть **способы** смены ip  на **Android** **программно** (самому **создать** программу и пользоваться ей как самому пожелается), рассказывайте **любые** **методы** главное чтобы они были **программными**, желательно с указанием **версий** Android на которых эти методы поддерживаются. А также способы реализации этих **методов**.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, стоит сказать, что в сети 3G/4G не получится сменить ip, который вам выдаётся провайдером. Можно только в локальной Wi-Fi сути статичный ip задать.

До API 17 использовали [`Settings.System`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html):

```
final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP, 1);
Settings.System.putString(cr, Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_IP, "you.re.ip.addr");
```

Нужно разрешение `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`.

Но теперь оно deprecated, нужно использовать [`WifiManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html).

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста как использовать WifiManager

Comment: @АртикКозорун я же не могу за вас всё написать )

Comment: Ладно, а каким образом это можно сделать через VPN, можно ли программно создать профиль VPN, тоесть так же как его создает пользователь, только прогаммно (странно как то сказал, но думаю понятно)